# Check if Java Class is commented in SVN Precommit hook

Tags: java, svn, pre-commit-hook, autodoc

I want to ensure that a Java class is commented, before someone commits something into the SVN repository. 
So I want to realize the following workflow:

1. User changes something in a class
2. User wants to commit class
3. Before executing the commit to the repository, SVN or something else checks if there are comments before the class and before `public` methods (for Java AutoDoc).
4. If there are comments => Commit, Otherwise return Error message

How can I realize this? I found a lot about pre-commit hooks. But everything was about checking if the commit message/comment is set.

It would be very nice and helpful if someone could provide a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, using [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/).

First, download the CheckStyle jar, and install it somewhere.
Then, create a new [xml config file](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html) for CheckStyle to check if your public methods/classes have some JavaDoc (you can call it **javadoc_check.xml** for instance):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
                    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="JavadocMethod">
            <property name="scope" value="public"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocType">
            <property name="scope" value="public"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

Once it's done, you can create you pre_commit hook, like that:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

CHECKSTYLEJAR=/path/to/checkstyle-5.7/checkstyle-5.7-all.jar
CHECKSTYLECONFIG=/path/to/javadoc_check.xml

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
JAVA=/usr/bin/java

EXITSTATUS=0
ERRORMARKER=__ERROR_MARKER__

# Create temporary dir
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)

# Iterate on the files commited
while read changeline;
do
    # Get the filename
    file=${changeline:4}

    # Check if it's an Updated or Added java file
    if [[ $file == *.java && ($changeline == U* || $changeline == A*) ]] ; then
        # Get the file content in a temporary file
        $SVNLOOK cat -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" "$file" > $TMPDIR/${file##*/}

        echo -e "\n=> Checking $file"
        # Check the file with checkstyle
        ( $JAVA -jar $CHECKSTYLEJAR -c $CHECKSTYLECONFIG $TMPDIR/${file##*/} 2>&1 || echo "$ERRORMARKER" 1>&2 ) | sed -e "s{$TMPDIR/{{"

        # Delete the temporary file
        rm $TMPDIR/${file##*/}
    fi
done < <($SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS") 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | grep "$ERRORMARKER" && EXITSTATUS=1 # Check for errors

# Delete temporary dir
rmdir $TMPDIR

exit $EXITSTATUS
```

Don't forget to change the path to the CheckStyle jar and CheckStyle config.

The next time you will try to commit a java file without JavaDoc comment on a public method/class, the commit will be cancelled, and you will have an error message:

```
$ svn commit
Sending        test.java
Transmitting file data .svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:

=> Checking test.java
Starting audit...
test.java:9:1: Missing a Javadoc comment.
Audit done.

svn: E165001: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn: E165001:    '/path/to/project/svn-commit.1.tmp'
$
```

If you commit more than one file, all the files will be checked, and the commit will be authorized only if all the modified/added java files have JavaDoc comments.