# Integrate Checkstyle with SVN pre commit hook in windows .bat file

Tags: svn, checkstyle, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

We have setup VisualSVN server in windows 7. Created repositories and committed the code into the repositories.

Planning to implement pre-commit hooks to prevent commit which is not following Java conventions. We are planning to use checkstyle, PMD and Findbug for that purpose.

We have seen a lot of example for SVN pre-commit hook using the shell script and python (SVNchecker) but our requirement is to create the batch file (.bat) to integrate checkstyle, PMD and Findbug.

Question is **How to integrate check style, PMD, and Findbug with svn pre-commit using window (.bat) file?**

We know the cons of doing it on the pre-commit hook but our source code is not bigger in the size and it is our requirement.

One of the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796264/check-if-java-class-is-commented-in-svn-precommit-hook) check style + svn pre-commit hook using the shell script.

Thanks,

Comment: What is your question anyway?

Comment: Added questions thanks @StackVictor